# Problems with integrating Millennial Media with Admob Mediation

Tags: iphone, ios, admob, millennial-media

I'm currently trying to integrate Millennial Media with Admob Mediation so I can display its interstitial ads on my iPhone app. Everything is working OK and I'm able to display the test ad (my app hasn't been approved yet), but when I close an ad, `interstitialDidDismissScreen` is not being triggered. I know that I've implemented the delegate correctly and it works with other ad networks so I know the problem is not on my end. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was hesitating on responding until I got a definite ETA on the adapter fix. We're posting updated adapters this afternoon, so check [the download page](http://docs.millennialmedia.com/iOS-SDK/iOSAdMobAdapter.html) two hours after the time-stamp on this post.

If this is an urgent request, put in a request on [the support page](https://tools.mmedia.com/user/supportDevPortal) and I can send you the updated adapter library that way, too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Millennial Media support, and the guy told me this was a known bug that they're currently trying to fix and will have an updated adapter sometime early next week (I'll update my answer when it's available).